# how can i show month in text insted of month number

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

how can i show month in text insted of month number in bootstrap date picker. can any one help me to find this solution??

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
});
```

```html
 <input  type="text"  id="datepicker" placeholder="select-date & month">
```

Comment: Which datepicker are you using?  There's probably a format for it, eg `format: "mmm-yyyy"`

Comment: yes this example format: "mmm-yyyy" month will show as like jan,feb.... and year is in by default format only i want is to change month number to text

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r4qtgk38/2/